# Docker image not accessible over exposed port

Tags: docker, tensorflow, cloud-foundry, swisscomdev

I've installed a tensorflow serving docker image in to the Swisscom AppCloud

https://github.com/tensorflow/serving/blob/master/tensorflow_serving/tools/docker/Dockerfile

Locally I'm able to call the REST endpoint over the port 8501

Based on the logs I would say the docker image started fine on the AppCloud

```
2019-02-12 22:30:50 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR 2019-02-12 21:30:50.937438: I tensorflow_serving/model_servers/server.cc:302] Exporting HTTP/REST API at:localhost:8501 ...
2019-02-12 22:30:50 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR [evhttp_server.cc : 237] RAW: Entering the event loop ...
2019-02-12 22:30:52 [CELL/0] OUT Container became healthy
```

The dockerfile exposes two ports: 8500 for gRPC and 8501 for REST

If I try to access the docker image through the mapped route e.g. https://predicition.scapp.io/ always a

```
502 Bad Gateway: Registered endpoint failed to handle the request.
```

is returned.

Am I missing any additional configuration? My understanding is, that CF uses the exposed ports from the docker image to map the incoming traffic?

---

**Update**

If I check the route_mapping there is no port, could that be the issue?
[image]

Comment: I can see that in request you are using port 443 as its an https call. How is request routed from 443 to 8501 on your machine where you have exposed the docker port. Also is your machine 8501 port opened?

Comment: That’s the job of CF: https://docs.cloudfoundry.org/devguide/deploy-apps/push-docker.html#port_config

Comment: The log shows it's available on `localhost:8501`. Does that mean it's only bound to localhost and not exposed on an IP address that is accessible elsewhere?

Comment: I dont understand how routing will work from 443 to 8501. From what i have understand reading doc is, EXPOSE command will expose that port on your instance. But i think you need to create a route from 443 to 8501 as it is mentioned in doc that CF recieves traffic on 80/443(Link : https://docs.cloudfoundry.org/devguide/deploy-apps/prepare-to-deploy.html#ports). Please read this doc : https://docs.cloudfoundry.org/devguide/deploy-apps/routes-domains.html . I think you need to create a route from 443 to 8501.

Comment: If there are two ports exposed, my understanding is that Diego will map to the lower of the two, which in your case would be 8500. That may be what's happening here. Any chance you could change the image to expose different ports? Even if just as a temporary test.  https://docs.cloudfoundry.org/adminguide/docker.html#run-monitor

Comment: I did change it. Sadly no change in behavior